# Github API missing event `moved_columns_in_project`

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to retrieve the `moved_columns_in_project` event (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/issue-event-types?apiVersion=2022-11-28#moved_columns_in_project) from the issues of a repository. I'd like to run some historical analysis on the corresponding timestamps, but I'm not able to get those events.

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
In [21]: import aiohttp
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: async def fetch_issues():
    ...:     owner = "xxx"
    ...:     repository = "xxx"
    ...:     token = "xxx"
    ...:     headers = {
    ...:         "Accept": "application/vnd.github.json",
    ...:         "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    ...:     }
    ...:     params = {
    ...:         "state": "all",
    ...:     }
    ...: 
    ...:     resps = []
    ...:     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    ...:         async with session.get(
    ...:                 f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository}/issues",
    ...:                 headers=headers, params=params
    ...:         ) as resp:
    ...:             json = await resp.json()
    ...: 
    ...:         resps.append(json)
    ...:         events = []
    ...: 
    ...:         for r in json:
    ...:             events_url = r['events_url']
    ...:             async with session.get(
    ...:                     events_url,
    ...:                     headers=headers, params=params
    ...:             ) as resp:
    ...:                 json = await resp.json()
    ...: 
    ...:             events.append(json)
    ...: 
    ...:         resps.append(events)
    ...: 
    ...:         return resps
    ...: 

In [22]: import itertools

In [23]: set(ev['event'] for ev in itertools.chain.from_iterable(iss_events for iss_events in iss[1]))
Out[23]: 
{'assigned',
 'closed',
 'head_ref_deleted',
 'head_ref_force_pushed',
 'labeled',
 'mentioned',
 'merged',
 'referenced',
 'renamed',
 'review_requested'}
```

As you can see, there's no issue with either a single event `moved_columns_in_project`. Am I missing something?